# stream link and IPv6 сеть

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, ipad

Apple зареджектила приложение. "all apps must support IPv6" Я использую AVPlayer для проигрывания аудио стриминга и AFNetworking 3.~ для загрузки данных.

сылка для аудио потока http://more.fm:8000/more256 которая содержит ":8080" порт. Это может быть зареджектино из за того что в ссылке прописан порт? У меня нету возможности протестировать приложение в ipv6 сети

Comment: а почему нет возможности протестировать в ipv6?

Comment: провайдер как я понимаю не подерживает ipv6. http://ipv6-test.com/ показывает что нету соеденение по ipv6

Comment: вот тут есть пример как создать ipv6, не уверен что поможет, но все таки https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010220-CH213-SW1